# Send some of the properties to slack from azure alerts

Tags: azure, slack, azure-logic-apps

How can I send some of the properties from AzureMonitorMetricAlert

The full JSON looks like:

```
{ 
   "schemaId":"AzureMonitorMetricAlert",
   "data": { 
      "version":"2.0",
      "properties":null,
      "status":"Active",
      "context": { 
         "timestamp":"2019-04-30T14:19:49.4987935Z",
         "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/microsoft.insights/metricAlerts/500%20response%20code",
         "name":"500 response code",
         "description":"",
         "conditionType":"DynamicThresholdCriteria",
         "severity":"3",
         "condition": { 
            "windowSize":"PT5M",
            "allOf": [ 
                { 
                  "alertSensitivity":null,
                  "failingPeriods":null,
                  "ignoreDataBefore":null,
                  "metricName":"requests/failed",
                  "metricNamespace":"microsoft.insights/components",
                  "operator":null,
                  "threshold":null,
                  "timeAggregation":"Count",
                  "dimensions": [ 
                      { 
                        "name":"ResourceId",
                        "value":"xxxxxxxxx"
                     },
                      { 
                        "name":"request/resultCode",
                        "value":"500"
                     }
                  ],
                  "metricValue":null
               }
            ]
         },
         "subscriptionId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "resourceGroupName":"test",
         "resourceName":"test",
         "resourceType":"microsoft.insights/components",
         "resourceId":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test/providers/microsoft.insights/components/tests",
         "portalLink":"https://portal.azure.com/#resource/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/dsdsdsdsds"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I send message to the slack including text eg: "The alert for ${context.name} was sent."
I was trying with:

```
        "actions": {
            "Post_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['slack']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/chat.postMessage",
                    "queries": {
                        "channel": "CHT0EMJ3H",
                        "parse": "full",
                        "text": "tests::::::=>>>>> @{triggerBody()?['context']['name']}"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. If I use just `"text": "tests::::::=>>>>> @{triggerBody()}"` the full JSON is sent but it is hard to read it since it is parsed as a string.

Comment: Checkout this answer from MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7316b775-0fb4-44aa-a93f-1dcc8a85abad/get-some-properties-from-json-produced-by-slack?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: The solution from msdn works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the properties because the output of `triggerbody()` is a string. so you could parse the string to Json firstly then read the properties.

So you need to use the `Parse Json` action, the Content is the `@triggerBody()` and the schema click `Use sample payload to generate schema` and input the Json. With this action you will be able to read the properties.

I test with HTTP Request trigger and send an mail, reading the `conditionType` with `@{body('Parse_JSON')?['data']?['context']?['conditionType']}`.

[image]

[image]